# How to take my PHP form handler pages into WordPress to connect with PayPal API

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I'm trying to integrate a form like [this](http://www.wilsonkeenan.com/learningphp/DoDirectPayment.php) into Wordpress

This form works perfectly with the PayPal API sandbox.  However, when I tried to move this work over to the WP site of my organization, globalcitizenyear.org/donate/donation-form-2/, I keep coming up short.

Anyone have any tips to keep in mind when doing this? What steps would you take first to make this happen in Wordpress - any details on what to avoid, or what potential hangups might be?

Answer (score 0):

Make a page called page-donation-form-2.php and load this code into it. You can leave in the get_header() and get_footer() tags if you want to have the site wrapper around the outside.

Make sure to change your form action also. And remember, that since this is in WordPress now, you will need to avoid some reserved form elements. Full list [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms).

If you have any trouble, please post your code here.